# Restrict access to register users in ASP.NET Web API and Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have created an ASP.NET Web API (v2) which I am securing using ASP.NET Identity (Individual User Accounts).  In the Web API project template Visual Studio 2015 provides code for this which included everything to allow users to register.  The only way to register seems to be via an API that is open to everyone.

I want to restrict access to the register functionality to a system administrator so that only specific users can be registered (by the system administrator) to use the Web API. How would this be done using ASP.NET Web API and Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cannot you secure Register endpoint with `[Authorize("Admin")]`  attribute?

Comment: Ok... and then I would need to add an administrator to the Identity database tables manually?  So the administrator can be authenticated.